# Name: price, dtype: int64)' is an invalid key

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

This is my csv file after converting it into pandas object.I am using multi-variable linear regression to create prediction.

```
    area    bedrooms    age price
0   2600    3.0 20  550000
1   3000    4.0 15  565000
2   3200    NaN 18  610000
3   3600    3.0 30  595000
4   4000    5.0 8   760000


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
import math

df = pd.read_csv("/home/alie/Documents/house.csv",delimiter=",",converters={"price":int})
d = math.floor(df['bedrooms'].mean())
df.bedrooms = df.bedrooms.fillna(d)
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
df.columns  = df.columns.str.strip().str.lower().str.replace(' ', '_').str.replace('(', '').str.replace(')', '')
reg.fit(df[['area', 'bedrooms', 'age'],df.price])
```

when i do reg.fit it gives me this error, nay help regarding solving the issue will be helpful.

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-05a6adc5f668> in <module>
      9 reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
     10 df.columns  = df.columns.str.strip().str.lower().str.replace(' ', '_').str.replace('(', '').str.replace(')', '')
---> 11 reg.fit(df[['area', 'bedrooms', 'age'],df.price])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2925             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2926                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2927             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2928             if is_integer(indexer):
   2929                 indexer = [indexer]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2655                                  'backfill or nearest lookups')
   2656             try:
-> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:
   2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

TypeError: '(['area', 'bedrooms', 'age'], 0    550000
1    565000
2    610000
3    595000
4    760000
Name: price, dtype: int64)' is an invalid key
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invalid key error type usually refers to an incorrect index while trying to access the data frame. Check line 11 and make sure you are declaring df correctly. Could it be:

```
reg.fit(df['area', 'bedrooms', 'age'], df.price)
```

That way the fit methods gets two separate objects.